# Is it possible to get a list of facebook pages with insights access without the "manage_pages" permission?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find out if a Facebook User is able to view the insights of a certain Facebook page. I know that this is possible using the Open Graph API with an access token that has the "manage_pages" permission. Is this the only possible solution? I don't want to request the "manage_pages" permission just to find out if this certain user can view the insights. My app only requests the "view_insights" permission and I'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 3):

If its a specific page then you can get `<PAGE_ID>/insights` with the Graph API, all it requires is `read_insights` permission.

For getting list of pages a user administrating using either Graph API (`<USER_ID>/accounts`) or FQL (`SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid=<USER_ID>`) you'll have to request the `manage_pages` permissions